# Import .sql file using multiple threads?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a huge SQL file (around 69GB). I want to import it into my local database. All tables are InnoDB engine based.

---

I have tried standard ways of importing

```
mysql -u*** -p**** db_name < dump.sql
```

and

```
source /location/dump.sql
```

but these take too much time.

---

Is there any way in SQL or Python that we can create multiple threads corresponding to diff tables and import them? Is there any other method that can speed up the process?

Answer (score 0):

The restore you are doing:

```
    mysql -u*** -p**** db_name < dump.sql
```

is going to be the fastest way - in python you would have to do multiple inserts which would be a lot slower.

Comment: my idea was to somehow pickup diff tables from the dump and then run seprate dumping query using multithreading module in python but seprating it in diff sql tables is an issue

Answer (score 0):

You might analyze the dump file and try to send the inserts into different tables to different command streams, but I doubt it is worth the effort. Take into account that reading and redirecting adds another step into your processing chain, and that all 69 GB must pass this step.

Your main performance limitation is that all those data form a single stream, so all insert transactions are done sequentially. You might get some speedup by telling the database server to *not* write all the commit entries to the log immediately (= 1 synchronous write per transaction). The easiest way to do this would be

mysql -u*** -p*** dbname

set session innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0;

source /location/dump.sql

However, this will not reduce the total amount of data to write, so the speedup will be limited.

Comment: Yes I agree with you but thats a production database I dont even have permission to set the log variables so its of no use to me

Comment: You would not set the variable globally, you would do it only for the session in which you load the dump. AFAIK, there is nothing that prevents you from doing this within your command stream. Once that session terminates, the setting is moot. Of course we want commits to be logged ("stable storage" in DBMS terms) in general, but for an existing file this does not really matter as you can repeat that run in case of a crash.